# Add two statements underneath min function

Tags: pdftex

I'm trying to get two statements underneath the `min` function. I have already got one statement, using the following code:

```
\min_{\textbf{C}, \textbf{C}' \in \mathcal{C}}
```

I need to add one more statement below this. I already tried:

```
\min_{\textbf{C}, \textbf{C}' \in \mathcal{C}}_{\textbf{C} \neq \textbf{C}'}
```

but with no luck. Please excuse my ignorance if this is a silly question. I'm new to Latex.

How do I get two statements under the min function?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) starting with a `\documentclass` and ending with a `\end{document}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\substack`:

```
\[ \min_{\substack{\mathbf{C}, \mathbf{C}' \in \mathcal{C}\\ \mathbf{C} \neq \mathbf{C}'}} \]%[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: `\stackunder` or `\substack`?

Comment: `\substack` worked with the edit I made. The site for some reason had collapsed `\\\`` to `\\``

Comment: @egreg: `\substack`, of course. One of my frequent *lapsus calami*…